# jcifs.smb.SmbException: A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: samba, smb, jcifs

I am writing a simple android code to create a file in my SMB folder using jcifs. But I am getting the following exception.

> jcifs.smb.SmbException: A device attached to the system is not functioning.

The following is my code:

```html
try{

            String user = "X";
            String pass ="X";

            String sharedFolder="X";
            String path="X/"+sharedFolder+"/test.txt";
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("X",user, pass);
            SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
            SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
            smbfos.write("testing....and writing to a file".getBytes());
            System.out.println("completed ...nice !");


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. There were some issues with the jar file version. Moral of the story: use the latest jar of jcifs